# Почему выбирается только последнее поле из Mysql на python?

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

В базе точно знаю, что содержится несколько строк при выборке по данному условию, но возвращается только последнее. И через принт выводятся все, но возвращает только последнее.

```
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "SELECT name FROM baza WHERE ispoln = %s AND zakrytie = 0"
        cursor.execute(sql, (fio))
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
        return row
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: у вас возвращается последний row, который был обработан в цикле. нужно писать return cursor

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        result = []
        sql = "SELECT name FROM baza WHERE ispoln = %s AND zakrytie = 0"
        cursor.execute(sql, (fio,))
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
            result.append(row)
        return result
finally:
    connection.close()
```

вы можете так сделать если вы хотите узнать все запросы

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]